# Identify "CAPS" style icon in menu bar

Tags: icon, menu-bar

I've got the following icon in my menu bar:

[image: menu bar icon]

And I'm unsure of its origin. It looks like it should be the CAPS icon, but I don't have CAPS Lock on. Even if I switch between it on and off, the icon doesn't change.

It doesn't do anything when I click on it, or CMD+Click it.

Nothing untoward appears in my Activity Monitor.

Is there any way of identifying what it is, or what's caused it?

(12" Macbook running macOS 10.14.1)

Comment: It appears to from the app named CapSee. Check if you have that app installed.

Comment: I saw that, but don't have it installed.

Comment: Do you use any external keyboard or mice and have their vendor software installed?

Comment: You could try a screenshot tool that takes layered screenshots: one layer per window. E.g. Flying Meat’s Acorn. This will probably label the layers by window name. That should give you a clue as to the application’s name.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I have Logitech Options for a mouse, but that doesn't appear to have anything to do with it.

Comment: @PierreBernard There isn't a window to take a screenshot of? It's literally just the icon in the menu bar.

Comment: From a technical point of view this is a tiny window with no border or background.

Comment: @PierreBernard Gotcha! I'll download the free trial and give it a go.

Comment: That worked! It was 'Logitech Options Daemon' which was a layer of the screenshot. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Logitech Options adds this caps lock icon to your menu bar.